# Is QGLContext represent a GLXcontext

Tags: qt, opengl

I am newbie to openGL and trying to make sense out of the Qt OPenGl Api. Does QGLcontext represent a GLX context.?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does QGLcontext represent a GLX context.?

If running in a X11 environment yes.

If running under Windows it will be WGL context of course.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But is there WGLcontext in Windows?

Comment: Yes, WGL **is** the context for Windows. Qt abstracts the window/context creation systems, so the underlying type of a QGLContext will change with the OS.

Comment: Just to clarify one last time (Sorry If I am bugging about this too much) QGlContext--> GLXcontext in X11, IN windows QGLContext--> QGlContext. Is my understanding correct? Stupid me.... I was looking for a WGLcontext in QtAPI..;)

Comment: @Tharanga: The idea of Qt is to write a program once and compile them for all plattforms. Thus things that can be abstracted to all platforms won't get plattform specific classes. There are some X11 specific classes in Qt, but those are meant for supporting development of X11 specific programs, like window managers.